# Suggestions for the best Rails collaborative development stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, agile

Looking for some suggestions from the community for development stacks for collaborative environments.  Could you share what you have and what has worked for you or your team?

The following is probably too verbose for some and an expression of just some rambling thoughts I've had about my particular scenario as I'm working with a hatchling dev group.  SO, if you read it 1UP for you, otherwise, please just feel free to just share your thoughts re: the first question and what's worked for your team.

---

I have a situation where myself and a couple other developers are working together and I'd like to set up the "best" dev environment possible for Ruby on Rails development.  At the moment I use git and some of the usually accepted best practices for development, however the other guys are new and not terribly familiar with the shell, git, etc.  They're more from a php and monolithic environment.

I do have a central linux server that has been used hitherto for LAMP based dev for them.  I can retool it to anything I'd like it to be as I'm quite adept and experienced at Unix system and network admin.

***Could someone please suggest what may work well in this scenario?***  Again, ultimately we need to do collaborative development that has the lowest learning curve.  I'll be the only one deploying to Heroku until I feel comfortable with their experience.

I would like to put something together that can get us all up to speed quickly in a matter of a day vs a longer learning curve and then allow them to grow into the shell and so forth over the next couple weeks.

What I was thinking was more of a shared SMB (mixed Windows and Mac workstations) and SFTP unified projects folder that has either apache virtual hosts for each project or thin rack.  I'd continue to use my methods, but this could provide the flexibility for them to grow into this and be able to restart httpd or thin as per need.

Am I on the proverbial right track or has someone seen a better alternative?  A lot of things have crossed my mind such as Gitorious (since we'll have a lot of small projects needing to be tracked and an enormous GitHub account is not feasible), Heroku, OpenShift and a lot of other things, but I have enough uncertainty that I'd like to get some input from the community as to the right mix for great collaborative agile development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer but I think you have conflicting requirements: i.e. lowest learning curve vs low/free cost.

You say that GitHub is not feasible but it does offer unparalleled features for novice users. They can see commits on a website instead of on the commandline, can even edit files right in the browser (since yesterday, uses Ace) and gain insight into the branching/merging process.

Another paid option is http://cloud9ide.com/ which is also web-based.

I use my own development server as well but only use it for experienced people who need no hand-holding. If I were to let everyone on there the amount of support would consume my entire day.

It is my opinion that doing Rails development people should adopt the best practices in the field. See it like this: at least you won't burden them with learning Subversion or --eek-- CVS. Just seeing the commits on GitHub and having a discussion right after puzzling pieces of code is worth the money.

Comment: Right, one thing to note is that I'm talking about a short learning curve.  The problem presently is that we're needing to pop a couple of basic sites I've thrown at them out on BrowserCMS which eases the learning curve significantly since they're familiar with LAMP CMS concepts and much of that just translates over.  Then I expect them to be up to speed within about 1-3 weeks wrt git at least in terms of using it.  I was thinking that Gitorious may be better since we'll have a lot of small private projects (just no way you can put that many small private projects onto GitHub).

Comment: I'd hoped to get more input, but it appears this question's now pretty dead so I went ahead and accepted your response just so you'd not suffer from lack of interaction.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I couldn't be of greater help. I hope you find a solution that works.